# Python-3, my program doesn't show a negative image

Tags: python, python-3.x, cimage

So I need to follow the function in my textbook, to make an image negative and show the negative image. I've tried changing a few things in to replicate the previous function see to if that would change anything like typing in what image I want to have a negative of. It compiles and runs fine showing no errors it just doesn't show me a negative of my image, so I don't know whats the issue.

```
from cImage import *
def negativePixel(oldPixel):
    newRed = 255 - oldPixel.getRed()
    newGreen = 255 - oldPixel.getGreen()
    newBlue = 255 - oldPixel.getBlue()
    newPixel = Pixel(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)
    return newPixel`



def MakeNegative(imageFile):
    oldImage = FileImage(imageFile)
    width = oldImage.getWidth()
    height = oldImage.getHeight()

    myImageWindow = ImageWin("Negative Image", width * 2, height)
    oldImage.draw(myImageWindow)
    newIn = EmptyImage(width, height)

    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            oldPixel = oldImage.getPixel(col, row)
            newPixel = negativePixel(oldPixel)
            newIn.setPixel(col, row, newPixel)
newIn.setPosition(width + 1, 0)
newIn.draw(myImageWindow)
myImageWindow.exitOnClick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code wasn't compiling or running for me; I fixed a few things - indentation, `import image` (not `cImage`), not invoking `MakeNegative()`, parameters out of order, etc.  This works for me.  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9, cImage-2.0.2, Pillow-7.2.0.

```py
from image import *
def negativePixel(oldPixel):
    newRed = 255 - oldPixel.getRed()
    newGreen = 255 - oldPixel.getGreen()
    newBlue = 255 - oldPixel.getBlue()
    newPixel = Pixel(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)
    return newPixel



def MakeNegative(imageFile):
    oldImage = FileImage(imageFile)
    width = oldImage.getWidth()
    height = oldImage.getHeight()

    myImageWindow = ImageWin(width * 2, height, "Negative Image")
    oldImage.draw(myImageWindow)
    newIn = EmptyImage(width, height)

    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            oldPixel = oldImage.getPixel(col, row)
            newPixel = negativePixel(oldPixel)
            newIn.setPixel(col, row, newPixel)

    newIn.setPosition(width + 1, 0)
    newIn.draw(myImageWindow)
    myImageWindow.exitOnClick()

MakeNegative('Lenna_test_image.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I would suggest not using `from image import *`, though, because it clutters the namespace.